# Uploading Images via PHP to Localhost, Modifying Folder Permissions

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, permissions, upload

I'm testing my code at localhost, and the image upload I wrote will not move_uploaded_file(); to a particular folder.

I think it's a permissions issue with the folder, so how can I modify the permissions without using an FTP? .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php has an [chmod()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) function that can change the mode of files and directories.

Answer (score 0):

You'd use your regular filesystem tools, since it's localhost. On windows, that'd be the security stuff in Windows Explorer (right click the folder -> properties -> security tab). On Unix-ish systems, it'll be chown/chmod.